# Source of a quote by Ferdinand Rudio

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, teaching, euler-characteristics

I am looking for the source and context of this quote, found e.g. at [St Andrews](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Rudio.html):

> Only with the greatest difficulty is one able to follow the writings of any author preceding Euler, because it was not yet known how to ***let the formulas speak for themselves***. This art Euler was the first to teach.
>   — F. Rudio

(My emphasis. Slight variants suggest that it could originally have been in another language.)

Comment: Does [close](//mathoverflow.net/posts/347067/revisions)-mindedness also *speak for itself?* ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The quote is from a speech Rudio gave at the Town Hall in Zürich on the 6th December 1883; The German original is published in Felix Stähelin, *Reden und Vorträge* (1956, I have not found it online).

An English translation of the full speech is [here.](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Extras/Rudio_Euler.html) The translated quote reads as follows:

> But I cannot move on from reviewing Euler's mathematical work without
>   having considered an important factor. I have said that mathematics is
>   a language in which natural phenomena can be described in the simplest
>   and most comprehensive manner. With this in mind, you will understand
>   how important it is to express mathematical thoughts themselves as
>   concisely and clearly as possible. In this respect, Euler's work was
>   epoch-making. We can be safe to say that the whole form of modern
>   mathematical thinking has been created by Euler. If you read any
>   author immediately before Euler, it is very difficult indeed to
>   understand his terminology, as he has not yet learned how to let the
>   formulas speak for themselves. This art was not taught until Euler
>   came along.

Comment: Oh! [Same site](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Quotations/Rudio.html). How did you find it so fast? Google doesn’t.